# Evaluate: $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}}\:dx$

Tags: integration

Evaluate: $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}}\:dx$

I solved this question using u-substitution.

But I got two answers:

1) When $x=u^2 \implies \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}}\:dx =  
$2arcsinx $\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$ +c and

2) When $\sqrt{1-x}=u$ ===> $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}}\:dx$ = -2arcsin $\sqrt{1-x}$       +c

So why did I get two answers? Are they equivalent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integral of $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} dx $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289857/integral-of-int-frac1-sqrtx1-x-dx)

Comment: @tired: I don't see the form mentioned in this question, $-2\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)+C$ , in the [output from W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2Fsqrt%28x%281-x%29%29&lk=4&num=1) from the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent. Since
$$
\sin(\theta)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\theta)}\tag{1}
$$
if we set $u=\cos(\theta)$, upon taking the arcsin of equation $(1)$, we get 
$$
\arccos(u)=\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-u^2}\right)\tag{2}
$$
Therefore, setting $u=\sqrt{x}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\arcsin\left(\sqrt{x}\right)
&=\frac\pi2-\arccos\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\\
&=\frac\pi2-\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x}^2}\right)\\
&=\frac\pi2-\arcsin\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, your two answers differ by the constant of integration.

Answer (score 2):

another way is :
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}}\\=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}\\=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}+x-x^2}}\\=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}}\\=\int \frac{2dx}{\sqrt{1-(2x-1)^2}}\\$$now use this substittuion $u=2x-1$ so $du=2dx$ $$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=arcsin(u)=arcsin(2x-1)$$ but  answers are equal $$(arcsin(2x-1))'=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-(2x-1)^2}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4x-4x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}$$

Comment: Doesn't $\require{cancel}\arcsin(u)=\cancel{2}\arcsin(2x-1)$?

Comment: I had a typing mistake .correct it

Comment: This is correct since $$\begin{align}\sin\left(\frac\pi2-2\theta\right) &=\cos(2\theta)\\ &=1-2\sin^2(\theta)\end{align}$$ Therefore, letting $\sqrt{x}=\sin(\theta)$, we get $$ \frac\pi2-2\arcsin(\sqrt{x})=\arcsin(1-2x) $$ or equivalently $$ 2\arcsin(\sqrt{x})=\frac\pi2+\arcsin(2x-1) $$ so this answer differs by a constant of integration from the one in the question.